# strlen() returning 0

Tags: php, string, wordpress

Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong. `strlen()` keeps returning 0.

This is my code:

```
$tempstr = the_title();

if (strlen($tempstr) > 12) {
    echo substr($tempstr,0,9) . "...";  
} els e{
    echo $tempstr;
    echo strlen($tempstr);
}
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($tempstr);` ?

Comment: could you provide either the the_title() function or the result of print_r(the_title().':".$tempstr);?

Comment: Are you using WordPress?

Comment: Yes I am using wordpress. the_title() function just brings back a string.

Comment: @tgc8008 But what is in this string? `var_dump($tempstr);` = ???

Comment: var_dump brings back the text I am expecting. in this case its just a simple string title like "sunshine" but strlen wont count the length

Comment: Show us the return value of: `var_dump($tempstr);` the **full** and **exact** output!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that the WordPress function [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) does not return a string, but `echo`'s it. To get the title as a string, use [`get_the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title).

```
$tempstr= get_the_title();
if (strlen($tempstr) > 12){
    echo substr($tempstr,0,9)."...";    
}else{
    echo $tempstr;
    echo strlen($tempstr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. I would need to have a closer look at the codex